# SQL: Substring from the right

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to figure out a way to use the substring function or any other function in order to remove certain things from the right side of the sentence

For example:

```
Washington, USA
Michigan, USA
Tokyo, JAP
Seoul, KOR
```

So, in the above example, I want to remove ', USA' or ', JAP' using a function. The country code will always be 3 letters. So, the total spacing to be removed is 5 (3 characters, 1 space & 1 coma)

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL? Are you just looking for `LEFT() / RIGHT()` function?

Comment: You mean [`LEFT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)? `RIGHT` and `LEFT` are very common string manipulation functions.

Comment: MySQL has [`LEFT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_left) too.

Comment: @Sami Left & right function can be used when the city character size is always the same but it is not same in the above case. The country character always remains the same tho.

Comment: @Nexus there's nothing stopping the value of the second parameter for `LEFT` being an expression, rather than a literal integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using MySQL, then `SUBSTRING_INDEX` is probably the easiest way to do this:

```
SELECT
    'Washington, USA' AS state_country,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX('Washington, USA', ',', 1) AS state
FROM dual;
```

[image: screen capture of demo query]

### Demo

Comment: Perfect... Thanks

Comment: this is how I would do it, if the specification is to return the portion before the first comma. if the precise specification is to remove the last five characters, we can use a combination of CHAR_LENGTH and SUBSTRING functions; if part of the specification is to check the end of the string for a comma followed by a space and then three characters, we could do a check with a regular expression to check that.  +10

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that total spacing is five then you can use the SUBSTR function.  Like so:

SELECT SUBSTR("Washington, USA", 1, CHAR_LENGTH("Washington, USA") - 5);

Comment: better to use `CHAR_LENGTH` to return number of *characters*. `LENGTH` function returns number of *bytes*. that will be the same with with single byte characters, but we are in an age where multibyte charactersets are common.

Answer (score -1):

LEFT operator is used to take a specific number of character on the left of your string. Problem here is that you don't know how much character you need to take.

You can solve this by using the LOCATE MySQL function (if you actually use MySQL).

```
SELECT LEFT("Washington, USA", LOCATE(",","Washington, USA")-1);
```

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_left.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_locate.asp

EDIT : Tim answer is better

Comment: almost any answer without links to w3fools is a better answer.  https://web.archive.org/web/20130302014219/http://w3fools.com/